# User provided in Symfony2 does not log in

Tags: php, security, symfony

I'm following few tutorials along with the documentation, but I can't make my provided user in `security.yml` to log in. Here is my YML file that provides a username called `user` and a password `userpass`, as a simply user.

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: sha512

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user: { password: userpass, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            anonymous: ~
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/new, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/create, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/edit, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/delete, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

The `loginAction` is the same from the official documentation:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $authUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastUsernme = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('UserBundle:Login:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsernme,
        'error' => $error
    ));
}
```

I don't know what else I should paste here because every view, controller and route works perfectly. The only issue is that whenever I try to log in with that user and password the "BAD CREDENTIALS" message is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use plaintext encoder in order to be able to login with "userpass" (look at the example below)
or you can encode "userpass" to sha512 and replace "userpass" by the result

```
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

Comment: Great. That solved it. The above answer also helped me to realize if we'll use any encoder, the password must also be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

[This shows you](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/07wr/in-memory-style-user-authentication-and-authorisation-with-webform-login-box) the full example.

You can just pay attention to SecurityController and the security.yml file in the example then work out what else you're missing in your application.

**example security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    basic:
                        password: $2a$12$Mnp6eUx1AJ5YABwmprcu/OHo21klIpQ/PA7D7PdKx5SA4urdav6/e  #basic
                        roles: ROLE_USER
                    admin:
                        password: $2a$12$aRC0GRcjZS9bXfQYlpT8f.JkkrwuK0xZwKuoQ78i1CsErbHtriWLm  #admin
                        roles: ROLE_ADMIN
                    super:
                        password: $2a$12$7SeyjOot3/3Ez1c0Dm8W0u/EenNEs8ykOl16D5aKkJkzLEq4lvXP2  #super
                        roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login
            logout:
                invalidate_session: true
                path: /logout
                target: /

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/backend/superadmin, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/backend/secret, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/backend, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/country, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```